# Add Polyline on click and show next point on mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Not sure how to word my question in the title, but what I want to do is have a feature that behaves the same as the Your Places -> Maps -> Create Map on maps.google.com when you click the "Draw a Line" -> "Add Line or Shape" button. It starts a Polyline on the map and then shows a shadow line from that points to your mouse cursor so you can see what your line will be when you click again:

[image]

Is there a built-in options in the Google Maps API to do this? I have this much so far when a user clicks the map for the first time:

```
function startNewLine(latLng) {
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    draggable: true,
    editable: true,
  });

  line.setMap(boundaryMap);
  line.getPath().push(latLng);

  google.maps.event.clearListeners(boundaryMap, 'click');
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vg5pfgv/)

It starts a new line at the point that was clicked, but that's as far as I've gotten.

Answer (score 2):

Add a [`mousemove` event listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/map#Map.mousemove) to the map.  Use it to set the second (or next) vertex of the polyline.

```
boundaryMap.addListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (line && line.getPath() && line.getPath().getLength() > 0)
    line.getPath().setAt(1, e.latLng);
});
```

For multiple vertices:

```
boundaryMap.addListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  console.log("mousemove " + e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
  if (line && line.getPath() && line.getPath().getLength() > (nextV - 1))
    line.getPath().setAt(nextV, e.latLng);
})

function startNewLine(latLng) {
  line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    draggable: true,
    editable: true,
  });
  nextV = 1;
  line.setMap(boundaryMap);
  line.getPath().push(latLng);
  line.addListener('click', function(e) {
    nextV++;
    console.log("line click " + e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
  })
  line.addListener('dblclick', function(e) {
    console.log("line dblclick " + e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(boundaryMap, "mousemove");
  })
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(boundaryMap, 'click');
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4vg5pfgv/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
initMap();

var boundaryMap;
var line;
var nextV = 0;

function initMap() {
  boundaryMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), {
    center: {lat: 37.1, lng: -95.7},
    zoom: 5
  });

  boundaryMap.addListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log("click " + e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
    startNewLine(e.latLng);
  });
  boundaryMap.addListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    console.log("mousemove " + e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
    if (line && line.getPath() && line.getPath().getLength() > (nextV - 1))
      line.getPath().setAt(nextV, e.latLng);
  })
}

function startNewLine(latLng) {
  line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    draggable: true,
    editable: true,
  });
  nextV = 1;
  line.setMap(boundaryMap);
  line.getPath().push(latLng);
  line.addListener('click', function(e) {
    nextV++;
    console.log("line click " + e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
  })
  line.addListener('dblclick', function(e) {
    console.log("line dblclick " + e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(boundaryMap, "mousemove");
  })
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(boundaryMap, 'click');
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="mapContainer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Quick note that the polyline click events only take precedence when set to `editable`. Otherwise map level events continue to emit instead.